# How do I do this <a href>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates

```
http://www.twitter.com/home?status=Check out my page!
```

However, when it goes to the twitter page, it has %20 symbols replacing the spaces. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead.
http://www.twitter.com/home?status=Check+out+my+page!

Answer (score 2):

Read about url encoding
http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Answer (score 1):

The %20 is the URL encoding for a space. You don't have to worry about that as the web server will understand it properly. Typically spaces are encoded in a URL.

Comment: Except if you knew how Twitter worked, you'd know you're supposed to a '+' instead of a space.

Comment: You can also use the + sign instead of %20